# Sharepoint 2010 Wiki question

Tags: wiki, html

I would like to know how can I make my wiki lib look like wikipedia as much as possible.

By that i mean how can I:

make a link to the document (like the "Contents" menu)?

implement the "sections"?

i am a developer but i was wondering if theres a way to do it without messing with the html, since most of my users don't even know what HTML is... like [[Home]] sends you to the page named Home... maybe there's a [*Section 1*]...

Answer (score 1):

No actual mechanism exists to help you do that, but workarounds could be envisioned. example:

1. Rely on the Markup Styles and Style to locate actual HEADINGs -
   helping you to build TOC
2. Use jQuery selectors heavily to modify on the fly wiki pages and inject elements with dynamically generated TOCs

See here an example to get you started http://www.n8d.at/blog/enhance-wiki-page-layout-by-adding-a-navgational-table-of-contents/

For the "sections" concepts, you could build your own DataView web part which combined with some rules imposed on file naming could help also rebuild across pages in a dedicated library some roll-up.

Comment: looks like a pretty un-straightforward solution... usability is doubtfull...

Comment: not sure i full understand your comment, hope is pretty clear that a straightforward solution it is not, according to stated  requirements, but workarounds are.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint 2010 does not support this as a native feature and major customization would be required to do so, possibly involving a html generator